# Can memory read and write operations overlap in CUDA programming?

Tags: cuda, gpu, nvidia, gpu-shared-memory

I know in CUDA programming, memory reads at different levels can overlap. For example, data transfers from global memory to shared memory and from shared memory to registers can overlap. But can read and write operations at the same memory level overlap, such as overlapping reads and writes to shared memory or global memory?

I checked the CUDA C++ Programming Guide, but couldn't find the relevant content. I think it's not possible, but I'm not entirely sure.

Comment: Do you mean whether a thread can issue multiple independent loads or stores without waiting the entire latency time of the previous operation? Or do you mean whether a thread can issue one store followed by a load that may overlap; meaning whether the hardware can handle store-to-load forwarding?

Comment: @Homer512 Thank you very much for your comment. My question pertains to the second scenario, but it's not entirely about store-to-load forwarding. When a thread issues a store followed by a load, are these instructions executed sequentially or in parallel by the hardware? Is it the case that if the target addresses are the same, store-to-load forwarding can be utilized, but if the addresses are different, the hardware needs to process the store and load sequentially?

Comment: How the GPU actually execute instruction should not be relevant. In fact, it may change from one architecture to another. What matters is what the programming model defines. AFAIK, the execution of each thread is sequentially consistent like on CPU (it would be quite insane otherwise IMHO). AFAIK, when multiple thread of the same block performs memory operations, they are not mandatory in sync but there is an instruction to sync them in CUDA so to avoid such issue. AFAIK, when two threads of two different blocks perform that, there is no way to sync them besides atomics.

Comment: I couldn't find any official or reverse-engineered information on this. I don't recall ever seeing extra latency caused by stores followed by loads so I assume the regular pipelining can deal with it. Especially with `__private__` memory such as register spilling it would be very obvious if the hardware couldn't handle it reasonably well. Since not all architectures use the L1 cache for private memory, I assume the L2 cache and global memory can also deal with it. But these are assumptions. The Best Practices Guide doesn't cover it so we probably don't need to worry about it

Comment: @Homer512 You mean `__local__`?

Comment: @paleonix thanks for the correction. Yes, that's what I mean